# Set DEBUG enviroment variable in c

Tags: c

I have a code (not programmed by me) in which I have some parts where I have something like that:

```
#if CORE_DEBUG
    ee_printf("State Bench: %d,%d,%d,%04x\n",seed1,seed2,step,crc);
#endif
```

My question is: what is the correct way to set up this environment variable?

EDIT: I am building the code with [this](https://github.com/eembc/coremark-pro/blob/master/util/make/gcc.mak) Makefiles.

Comment: This `CORE_DEBUG` is not an environment variable but a C preprocessor macro or preprocessor symbol.

Comment: Please [edit] your questions and add details about your development environment. Do you run the compiler manually? Do you use a build system like CMake? Do you use an IDE? Which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a compilation flag, like `-DCORE_DEBUG`.

In some build environments you can enable/disable these as part of your build profile.